# How many orbits are there in the group action $A\colon 3\mathbb{Z} \to\mathbb{Z}_{6}$ with action given by $(3n,m)=(3n+m)\bmod6$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

I am having difficulty trying to understand this question. All I know is that $3\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_6$ are both groups, that is:

$$3\mathbb{Z}=\{\dotsc, -6, -3, 0, 3, 6 \dotsc\}$$

$$\mathbb{Z}_6= \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$$

I took $\mathbb{Z}_6$ to be the set, and taking elements of $\mathbb{Z}_6$ to be represented by $m$. On the other hand, represented the elements of $3\mathbb{Z}$ with $n$. 
Hence, if I were to take $m=0$ then $n=0$ and applying the action:

$$(3(0), (0))=(3(0) + 0) \bmod 6 = 0$$

I repeated the procedure for:

$m=1$, $n=3$ giving $4$

$m=2$, $n=6$ giving $2$

$m=3$, $n=9$ giving $0$

And for some reason, I ended up with only: $\{0, 2, 4\}$ which I assumed to be my orbits. 
I am not sure whether I've applied the action correctly, for most of the work I've only made assumptions. In fact I would really need your help for enlightenment. Thanks.

Comment: Just a small comment on the title - an action of $3\mathbb{Z}$ on $\mathbb{Z}_6$ isn't a map $3\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}_6$. You could write it as a map $3\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}_6\to\mathbb{Z}_6$ though; and then you probably want to write $(3n,m)\mapsto(3n+m)\bmod6$, rather than using $=$.

Comment: Also, are you saying you think that $\{0,2,4\}$ is an orbit? Or that each of $\{0\}$, $\{2\}$ and $\{4\}$ is an orbit?

Comment: @MattPressland , to be honest, I was thinking of {0, 2, 4}, but do correct me if i'm wrong. However, I do recall that the order partitions the set. So, if were to say that the order is 3, then perhaps, then it should have been {0}, {2}, {4} ?

Comment: Actually neither is correct - I should probably have said that - I was trying to work out where your misunderstanding is. I'm still not sure I understand your method. An orbit is a subset of the space being acting on, in this case $\mathbb{Z}_6$, and the orbits collectively must partition the space. To find an orbit, you have a to pick an element $m$ of $\mathbb{Z}_6$, and act on it by every element of $3\mathbb{Z}$; in this case this means the orbit of $m$ is $\{3n+m\bmod 6:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ - does that make things clearer?

Comment: @MattPressland ,did you mean "neither" {0,2,4} or {o}, {2}, {4} is correct?

Comment: Yes. They certainly aren't all the orbits, because they don't cover $\mathbb{Z}_6$, and in fact none of those $4$ sets is an orbit.

Comment: @MattPressland, I think I can see things clearly now, thank you.

Comment: Great - I will summarise some comments in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compute the orbits of $m\in\mathbb{Z}_6$, you need to find the set $\{3n+m\bmod6:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, as this is the set of all elements of $\mathbb{Z}_6$ obtained by acting on $m$ by some element $3n$ of $3\mathbb{Z}$.

Thus you need to compute $3n+m\bmod{6}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ - note in particular that there is no relationship between $n$ and $m$.

You need to repeat this procedure for each element of $\mathbb{Z}_6$, although remember that orbits only intersect if they are equal. For example, you will compute that $3$ is in the orbit of $0$ (because $3=3\times 1+0\bmod6$), so the orbit of $3$ is equal to the orbit of $0$, and you don't need to calculate the orbit of $3$ separately.

If you know it, you could make things more efficient by using the Orbit-Stabiliser theorem to prove that the size of every orbit is $2$, which allows you to work out the number of orbits without having to compute the orbits themselves.